# How do I convert a string value to be returnable in a method that returns an abstract class type?

Tags: c#, .net, redis, json-deserialization, stackexchange.redis

New to C# and OOP here, but I am setting a simple string value of "Hello World" into Redis Cache. And what I want to do is to get that RedisValue from Redis Cache and deserialize it as a string and then return it in a method that has a return type of MethodBase (which is an abstract class). But I am running into a parsing error. **Unexpected character encountered while parsing value: v. Path '', line 0, position 0.**

The MethodBase abstract class just has some properties like id, name, email, createdAt, etc... Is it even possible to return a deserialized string like "Hello World" as this MethodBase?

My method for getting data from the Redis Cache is below.

```
public async Task<ModelBase> GetData(string key) {
    var data = await this.db.StringGetAsync(key); // This is a RedisValue of "Hello World".
    return (ModelBase)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(data); // Error here 
}
```

Anyone have any suggestions on how to keep the ModelBase return type in the method, but also be able to convert the RedisValue of "Hello World" into a ModelBase return type?

Comment: Could you please describe the relation between this string in Redis Cache and ModelBase ? Does it describe any property within ModelBase ?

Comment: If you Deserialize to ModelBase, then your string should be JSON with fields for ModelBase. It can't be any string, b/c then deserializer will not know how to deserialize it into object.

Comment: The string is just a random string that I am using for unit testing. Basically to test if the get/set methods work for redis cache. Which they do, but my get method needs to keep this ModelBase return type for my actual application, that's why I can't change it. Any suggestions on what I can do?

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a case you encounter while Unit testing (*believe you are interested only in the Redis retrival functionality, and not deserialization while writing your test case*), one approach would be move the actual serialization code to a custom Service (as you cannot mock static methods like `JsonConvert.DeserializeObject`). For example,

```
public interface ICustomSerializerService
{
    string Serialize<T>(T item);
    T Deserialize<T>(string data);
}

public class CustomSerializerService: ICustomSerializerService
{
    public string Serialize<T>(T item) => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
    public T Deserialize<T>(string data) => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<T>(data);
}
```

You could now inject the `ICustomSerializerService` to your method.

```
public async Task<ModelBase> GetData(string key, ICustomSerializerService service) {
    var data = await this.db.StringGetAsync(key); // This is a RedisValue of "Hello World".
    return service.Deserialize<ModelBase>(data); 
}
```

This would allow you to `mock` the ICustomSerializerService (which is not quite the target of your unit test, I assume) using frameworks like Moq and FakeItEasy, while unit testing the functionality of `GetData()` method.